# Как адаптировать элемент на Bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap4

Почему неправильно отображается номер телефона при уменьшении экрана?

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 text-left">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </div>

                    <div class=" col-lg-2 offset-lg-4  align-self-center phone text-right"><a href="#">+7 495 771 05 08</a></div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 align-self-center text-right"><button class="button header-btn ">получить консультацию</button></div>
                </div>[![шпатлевка][1]][1]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: из-за offset-lg-4, по всей видимости